# Invalid redeclaration compiler error on generic type extension

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, generics

My question is about some compiler error I'm getting when dealing with generic types with Swift.

So at the moment I'm running into this issue where I'm trying to extend `Dictionary` with `where` clauses by adding static variables and functions.
See an example below:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == String {
    static func foo() -> [String: String] {
        return [
            "bar": "bar",
            "baz": "baz"
        ]
    }
}
```

The issue now arises when I'm extending `Dictionary` again with a different generic conformance such as:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Int {
    static let foo: [String: Int] = [
            "bar": 0,
            "baz": 1
        ]
}
```

Note that `Value` is changed from `String` to `Int` and that `foo` in the second extension is declared as a `let`.
This now shows the following compiler error:

```
Invalid redeclaration of 'foo'
```

However, if I change both implementations of `foo` to be a static function or both to be a static `let` or `var`, it compiles fine.

Are there some kind of Swift shenanigans that I'm missing?

Comment: You can't declare method and property with same name in `Swift`. `where` clause will throw compiler error when the method/property is called with wrong constraints but the method/property will show for any kind of `associated` types.

Comment: Seems to be a known bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8123.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, I forgot to check there, that seems to be a know bug indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a known bug/restriction, see [SR-8123 – Invalid redeclaration of `name` when creating a func `name()` in a different extension of the same type with different `where` clause](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8123):

> However, the compiler fires an invalid redeclaration error if an extension defines a function with the same name as a variable defined in another extension.

and

> I think we should make this legal – currently we're always considering variables to conflict with non-variables (and functions with non-functions) if their overload signatures conflict, regardless of the generic environment. But if the generic environment differs, IMO it's reasonable to allow to allow the overload.